# Compilation error in java

Tags: java, eclipse

This code works in Eclipse, but when I try to submit the 'Test' problem on the SPOJ site, it gives me a compilation error.

Can you please tell me why?

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in) ;
        int n ;
        while(true )
        {
            n =input.nextInt() ;
            if(n==42)
                break ;
            else 
            System.out.println(n) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error message in your question.

Comment: i don't have a compilation error in my eclipse !
but SPOJ website tell me that !!?

Comment: you probably forgot to include the imports on the website, make sure you copy **all of your code**

Comment: i copy it all .. i'm sure ! but i wonder if the site doesn't accept all the libraries !! maybe ??

Comment: *when I try to submit the 'Test' problem on the SPOJ site, it gives me a compilation error.* What compilation error?

Comment: @nem This code doesn't need any imports.

Comment: but the compilation error doesn't appear in this website !
it just tell me that i have the compilation error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to name your class "**Main**" for it to work on SPOJ.

See this forum post for more information: https://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37